# Android Physcal Menu Button Event

Tags: android, button, menu, click

I want to handle physcal menu button event for block user who want to exit my application.
I tried onKeyDown(), onClick() and onCreateOptionsMenu() override methods. None of them doesnt work for me.
**How can I detect press physcal menu button?** Thank you.

PS: Android version 8.1.0

Answer (score 1):

what is "physcal menu button"? you are probably talking about Home button which is causing your app goes to background: thats not possible for security reasons ofc. if this would be possible then some unfair apps will take control on users device/screen, also there would be possibility of bug in some app causing that it can't be closed. Home* and Power buttons can't be hijacked or set for handling custom click only, at most you can detect these were pressed, but still they do their job

*well, Home nowadays is a gesture

Comment: I mean, there is 3 button on device; back, home and menu like all android devices. I can handle back onBackpressed() event. I also want to handle menu button that opens a screen which shows you all opened applications.

Comment: @piruzi SAme answer as he already gave you-  those are system buttons handled by the system and you don't get access to them for security reasons.  Also the 3rd button hasn't been menut in 5 or 6 years, the 3rd button is recents.  Menu moved from a physical button to just being the 3 dot icon in the mid 2010s.

Comment: I know, but that s a special device for only one purpose and has 3 button at bottom of screen. I just want to know if I can detect it. I though i can handle it because back button event working well.

Comment: Gabe mentioned about old physical menu button present years ago on Android devices and removed waaay before Android 8.0. you could custom-handle it with `KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU` in `onKeyDown`. if this isn't firing then this button probably isn't menu button, but may have set same icon... if you click it and can switch between previously opened apps then this is [Recent button](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/recents) (also called Overview button) and you can't override it also. nowadays it is also a gesture as Home

Comment: btw. if you have some very-custom device with some modified system version it's worth noting this in question. additional screenshot, link to producers site or at least photo (if these buttons are physical) also welcome

Comment: [img]: https://www.hizliresim.com/1on51jx  thats the view of device buttons.

Comment: it looks like menu button, but might not be. old-fashioned menu button present in Android below 5 (afaik) could be handled with `KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU`. if this isn't working then this button only looks like old menu button, but it is probably Recent button (check if its opening overview) and you cant change its behavior

Comment: We could solved our problem in low level. As you said, probably, it's not possible to handle in android level. Thank you for your all efforts guys.